# PyQt5 Adding QCompleter to Existing QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcompleter

I am currently creating a SQL Editor and Query Wizard with PyQt5 and am running into an issue when trying to add a QCompleter to all my QPlainTextEdits in the wizard. All the UI is created with Qt Designer and is stored in a QStackedWidget.

I have read into Promoting the widget in Designer to my custom widget (TextEdit), which is a QTextEdit with the QCompleter model interface.

My question is, how can one set the completer model to an object that is already created? Is there a way to hold off on initializing it until after the completer is set? In another section of the program, I am able to add the widget after its set due to the functionality, but there must be a better way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code that I use to set the way that works.

```
tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(tab)

self.completer = QCompleter(self)


self.all_autocomplete_words.extend(sql_words)
self.all_autocomplete_words = pd.Series(
    self.all_autocomplete_words).sort_values().drop_duplicates().tolist()
#print(self.all_autocomplete_words)
completer_model = QStringListModel(self.all_autocomplete_words, self.completer)

self.completer.setModel(completer_model)
self.completer.setModelSorting(QCompleter.CaseInsensitivelySortedModel)
self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
self.completer.setWrapAround(False)
# print(self.auto_completion_words)
# print(self.all_autocomplete_words)
self.completingTextEdit = TextEdit(dict_words=self.auto_completion_words,
                                   list_words=self.all_autocomplete_words, parent=tab)
self.completingTextEdit.setCompleter(self.completer)
self.completingTextEdit.setPlaceholderText('SQL Script')
horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.completingTextEdit)

#sql_ws.setPlaceholderText('SQL Script')
self.sql_tab.addTab(tab, key)
```

Edit:

Here is the base class for the minimum example...

```
from min_example_fromui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QMenu, QAction, \
    QMessageBox, QTreeWidgetItemIterator, QAbstractItemView, QDialog, QShortcut, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,\
    QPushButton, QWhatsThis, QCompleter, QTextEdit, QProgressDialog, QTableWidgetItem, QTableView
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile, QStringListModel, Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject, pyqtSlot, QTimer, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor, QKeySequence, QTextCursor
import pandas as pd

class sqlWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(sqlWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.sql_words = [
            'ABORT'

        ]
        self.all_autocomplete_words = []
        self.auto_completion_words = {}
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_tab)

    def add_tab(self):
        tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(tab)


        self.completer = QCompleter(self)


        self.all_autocomplete_words.extend(self.sql_words)
        self.all_autocomplete_words = pd.Series(
            self.all_autocomplete_words).sort_values().drop_duplicates().tolist()
        #print(self.all_autocomplete_words)



        completer_model = QStringListModel(self.all_autocomplete_words, self.completer)

        self.completer.setModel(completer_model)
        self.completer.setModelSorting(QCompleter.CaseInsensitivelySortedModel)
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.completer.setWrapAround(False)
        # print(self.auto_completion_words)
        # print(self.all_autocomplete_words)
        self.completingTextEdit = TextEdit(dict_words=self.auto_completion_words,
                                           list_words=self.all_autocomplete_words, parent=tab)
        self.completingTextEdit.setCompleter(self.completer)
        self.completingTextEdit.setPlaceholderText('SQL Script')
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.completingTextEdit)

        # sql_ws.setPlaceholderText('SQL Script')
        self.sql_tab.addTab(tab, 'key')
        self.sql_tab.setCurrentWidget(tab)

class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, dict_words=dict, list_words=list, parent=None):
        super(TextEdit, self).__init__(parent)

        self._completer = None
        self.auto_complete_dict = dict_words
        self.all_autocomplete = list_words
        #Class Instances
        self.completion_prefix = ''


    def setCompleter(self, c):

        self._completer = c
        c.setWidget(self)
        c.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
        c.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        c.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)


    def insertCompletion(self, completion):
        if self._completer.widget() is not self:
            return

        tc = self.textCursor()
        extra = len(completion) - len(self._completer.completionPrefix())
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.Left)
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfWord)

        if self.completion_prefix.lower() == completion[-extra:].lower():
            pass
            #print('You inserted the word after it was completed')
        else:
            tc.insertText(completion[-extra:])
            #print('The text being inserted',completion[-extra:])
            self.setTextCursor(tc)
            self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(self.all_autocomplete, self._completer))

    def textUnderCursor(self):
        tc = self.textCursor()
        tc.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)
        #print('Here is the selected text under the cursor' , tc.selectedText())
        return tc.selectedText()

    def focusInEvent(self, e):
        #Open the widget where you are at in the edit
        if self._completer is not None:
            self._completer.setWidget(self)
        super(TextEdit, self).focusInEvent(e)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):

        isShortcut = False

        if self._completer is not None and self._completer.popup().isVisible():
            #print('Popup is up')
            # The following keys are forwarded by the completer to the widget.
            if e.key() in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Escape, Qt.Key_Tab, Qt.Key_Backtab):
                e.ignore()
                #self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(self.all_autocomplete, self._completer))
                # Let the completer do default behavior.
                return

        if e.key() == Qt.Key_E and e.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
            #Control + E was pressed.
            words = self.all_autocomplete
            self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(words, self._completer))
            isShortcut = True

        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Period:
            #This is how I will do the lookup functionality. Show when period is his, open the list of options.
            self.textCursor().insertText('.')
            self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.PreviousWord)
            self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.PreviousWord, QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
            dict_key = self.textCursor().selectedText().upper()
            #print('Dict Key' , dict_key)
            self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextWord)
            self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextWord)

            #print(dict_key)
            words = self.auto_complete_dict[dict_key]
            self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(words, self._completer))
            isShortcut = True

        if self._completer is None or not isShortcut:
            # Do not process the shortcut when we have a completer.
            super(TextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(e)

        ctrlOrShift = e.modifiers() & (Qt.ControlModifier | Qt.ShiftModifier)
        if self._completer is None or (ctrlOrShift and len(e.text()) == 0):
            return

        eow = "~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?,./;'[]\\-="
        hasModifier = (e.modifiers() != Qt.NoModifier) and not ctrlOrShift


        completionPrefix = self.textUnderCursor()
        self.completion_prefix = completionPrefix
        #print('CompletionPrefix :' , completionPrefix)

        if not isShortcut and (hasModifier or len(e.text()) == 0 or len(completionPrefix) < 2 or e.text()[-1] in eow):
            self._completer.popup().hide()
            return

        if completionPrefix != self._completer.completionPrefix():
            #Puts the Prefix of the word youre typing into the Prefix
            self._completer.setCompletionPrefix(completionPrefix)
            self._completer.popup().setCurrentIndex(
                    self._completer.completionModel().index(0, 0))

        cr = self.cursorRect()
        cr.setWidth(self._completer.popup().sizeHintForColumn(0) + self._completer.popup().verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width())
        self._completer.complete(cr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    '''These excepthook lines are to catch errors when using pyqt5'''
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook
    def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
        print(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.excepthook = exception_hook
    '''Error handling section to raise errors'''

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = sqlWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is my ui code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.sql_tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.sql_tab.setEnabled(True)
        self.sql_tab.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.sql_tab.setMovable(True)
        self.sql_tab.setObjectName("sql_tab")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label.setLineWidth(0)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.sql_tab.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.sql_tab)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.sql_tab.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "For Help, refer to the User Manual."))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "User Manual"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:18pt;\">SQL Editor Welcome Sheet</span></p><p><br/></p><p>Only List Reports Can be Ran by Worksheet. </p><p>All Other Reports are Ran Through the Query Builder.</p></body></html>"))
        self.sql_tab.setTabText(self.sql_tab.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "SQL Editor Home"))
```

Thanks!

Second Edit:

```
from min_example_fromui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QMenu, QAction, \
    QMessageBox, QTreeWidgetItemIterator, QAbstractItemView, QDialog, QShortcut, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,\
    QPushButton, QWhatsThis, QCompleter, QTextEdit, QProgressDialog, QTableWidgetItem, QTableView
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile, QStringListModel, Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject, pyqtSlot, QTimer, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor, QKeySequence, QTextCursor
import pandas as pd

    class sqlWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(sqlWindow, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.sql_words = [
                'ABORT'

            ]
            self.all_autocomplete_words = []
            self.auto_completion_words = {}
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_tab)

            self.completer = QCompleter(self)

            self.all_autocomplete_words.extend(self.sql_words)
            self.all_autocomplete_words = pd.Series(
                self.all_autocomplete_words).sort_values().drop_duplicates().tolist()
            # print(self.all_autocomplete_words)

            self.completer_model = QStringListModel(self.all_autocomplete_words, self.completer)
            self.completer.setModel(self.completer_model)
            self.completer.setModelSorting(QCompleter.CaseInsensitivelySortedModel)
            self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
            self.completer.setWrapAround(False)

            self.my_sqlbox = TextEdit(dict_words=self.auto_completion_words,
                                               list_words=self.all_autocomplete_words, parent=None)
            self.my_sqlbox.setCompleter(self.completer)
            self.my_sqlbox.setPlaceholderText('SQL Script')

        def add_tab(self):
            tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(tab)


            self.completingTextEdit = TextEdit(dict_words=self.auto_completion_words,
                                               list_words=self.all_autocomplete_words, parent=tab)
            self.completingTextEdit.setCompleter(self.completer)
            self.completingTextEdit.setPlaceholderText('SQL Script')
            horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.completingTextEdit)

            # sql_ws.setPlaceholderText('SQL Script')
            self.sql_tab.addTab(tab, 'key')
            self.sql_tab.setCurrentWidget(tab)

    class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
        def __init__(self, dict_words=dict, list_words=list, parent=None):
            super(TextEdit, self).__init__(parent)

            self._completer = None
            self.auto_complete_dict = dict_words
            self.all_autocomplete = list_words
            #Class Instances
            self.completion_prefix = ''


        def setCompleter(self, c):

            self._completer = c
            c.setWidget(self)
            c.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
            c.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
            c.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)


        def insertCompletion(self, completion):
            if self._completer.widget() is not self:
                return

            tc = self.textCursor()
            extra = len(completion) - len(self._completer.completionPrefix())
            tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.Left)
            tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfWord)

            if self.completion_prefix.lower() == completion[-extra:].lower():
                pass
                #print('You inserted the word after it was completed')
            else:
                tc.insertText(completion[-extra:])
                #print('The text being inserted',completion[-extra:])
                self.setTextCursor(tc)
                self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(self.all_autocomplete, self._completer))

        def textUnderCursor(self):
            tc = self.textCursor()
            tc.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)
            #print('Here is the selected text under the cursor' , tc.selectedText())
            return tc.selectedText()

        def focusInEvent(self, e):
            #Open the widget where you are at in the edit
            if self._completer is not None:
                self._completer.setWidget(self)
            super(TextEdit, self).focusInEvent(e)

        def keyPressEvent(self, e):

            isShortcut = False

            if self._completer is not None and self._completer.popup().isVisible():
                #print('Popup is up')
                # The following keys are forwarded by the completer to the widget.
                if e.key() in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Escape, Qt.Key_Tab, Qt.Key_Backtab):
                    e.ignore()
                    #self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(self.all_autocomplete, self._completer))
                    # Let the completer do default behavior.
                    return

            if e.key() == Qt.Key_E and e.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
                #Control + E was pressed.
                words = self.all_autocomplete
                self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(words, self._completer))
                isShortcut = True

            if e.key() == Qt.Key_Period:
                #This is how I will do the lookup functionality. Show when period is his, open the list of options.
                self.textCursor().insertText('.')
                self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.PreviousWord)
                self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.PreviousWord, QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
                dict_key = self.textCursor().selectedText().upper()
                #print('Dict Key' , dict_key)
                self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextWord)
                self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextWord)

                #print(dict_key)
                words = self.auto_complete_dict[dict_key]
                self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(words, self._completer))
                isShortcut = True

            if self._completer is None or not isShortcut:
                # Do not process the shortcut when we have a completer.
                super(TextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(e)

            ctrlOrShift = e.modifiers() & (Qt.ControlModifier | Qt.ShiftModifier)
            if self._completer is None or (ctrlOrShift and len(e.text()) == 0):
                return

            eow = "~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?,./;'[]\\-="
            hasModifier = (e.modifiers() != Qt.NoModifier) and not ctrlOrShift


            completionPrefix = self.textUnderCursor()
            self.completion_prefix = completionPrefix
            #print('CompletionPrefix :' , completionPrefix)

            if not isShortcut and (hasModifier or len(e.text()) == 0 or len(completionPrefix) < 2 or e.text()[-1] in eow):
                self._completer.popup().hide()
                return

            if completionPrefix != self._completer.completionPrefix():
                #Puts the Prefix of the word youre typing into the Prefix
                self._completer.setCompletionPrefix(completionPrefix)
                self._completer.popup().setCurrentIndex(
                        self._completer.completionModel().index(0, 0))

            cr = self.cursorRect()
            cr.setWidth(self._completer.popup().sizeHintForColumn(0) + self._completer.popup().verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width())
            self._completer.complete(cr)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys

        '''These excepthook lines are to catch errors when using pyqt5'''
        sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook
        def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
            print(exctype, value, traceback)
            sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
            sys.exit(1)
        sys.excepthook = exception_hook
        '''Error handling section to raise errors'''

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        main_window = sqlWindow()
        main_window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Static QPlainText from ui

[image]

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc, I edited my question above with a small working example and ui form. In this example, I am creating new tabs. What I want to be able to do is have a textbox already created that I add this TextEdit class and QCompleter functionality to.

Comment: What do you mean by "textbox"? I understand that you want a single QCompleter that all QTextEdit share. Am I correct?

Comment: Sorry, I mean QPlainText when I say textbox. And I want to be able to update a QPlainText box that I have within my model to assign a QCompleter to it. So I can add a new tab and assign it, but I also want to have a static QPlainText and assign a QCompleter to it.

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better what you want but in more detail since your description is confusing.

Comment: What I want is this:
A form created in Designer with a QPlainText that will be used for writing SQL.
When this form is loaded, I want to set a QCompleter to the QPlainText.
This QCompleter will change depending on the DB connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for those in the future who run into this problem, I attempted to promote the widget in Qt Designer. However, I ran into issues when trying to add the arguments for the QCompleter. What I had to end up doing was to remove the QPlainTextEdit upon load and then call a function to add the new TextEdit class that I created along with the QCompleter.

See code below:

```
from min_example_fromui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QMenu, QAction, \
    QMessageBox, QTreeWidgetItemIterator, QAbstractItemView, QDialog, QShortcut, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,\
    QPushButton, QWhatsThis, QCompleter, QTextEdit, QProgressDialog, QTableWidgetItem, QTableView
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile, QStringListModel, Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject, pyqtSlot, QTimer, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor, QKeySequence, QTextCursor
import pandas as pd

class sqlWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(sqlWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.sql_words = [
            'ABORT'
        ]
        self.all_autocomplete_words = []
        self.auto_completion_words = {}

        ##################Delete the existing QPlainTextEdit############
        self.my_sqlbox.deleteLater()


        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_tab)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.test)
        self.completer = QCompleter(self)

        self.all_autocomplete_words.extend(self.sql_words)
        self.all_autocomplete_words = pd.Series(
            self.all_autocomplete_words).sort_values().drop_duplicates().tolist()
        # print(self.all_autocomplete_words)

        self.completer_model = QStringListModel(self.all_autocomplete_words, self.completer)
        self.completer.setModel(self.completer_model)
        self.completer.setModelSorting(QCompleter.CaseInsensitivelySortedModel)
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.completer.setWrapAround(False)

        #######RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I CALL THE NEW TextEdit creation#######
        self.makeText()





    def add_tab(self):
        tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(tab)


        self.completingTextEdit = TextEdit(dict_words=self.auto_completion_words,
                                           list_words=self.all_autocomplete_words, parent=tab)
        self.completingTextEdit.setCompleter(self.completer)
        self.completingTextEdit.setPlaceholderText('SQL Script')
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.completingTextEdit)

        # sql_ws.setPlaceholderText('SQL Script')
        self.sql_tab.addTab(tab, 'key')
        self.sql_tab.setCurrentWidget(tab)

    def makeText(self):
        self.my_sqlbox = TextEdit(dict_words=self.auto_completion_words,
                                  list_words=self.all_autocomplete_words, parent=None)
        self.my_sqlbox.setCompleter(self.completer)
        self.my_sqlbox.setPlaceholderText('SQL Script')
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.my_sqlbox ,0, 1, 1, 1)

class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, dict_words=dict, list_words=list, parent=None):
        super(TextEdit, self).__init__(parent)

        self._completer = None
        self.auto_complete_dict = dict_words
        self.all_autocomplete = list_words
        #Class Instances
        self.completion_prefix = ''


    def setCompleter(self, c):

        self._completer = c
        c.setWidget(self)
        c.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
        c.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        c.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)


    def insertCompletion(self, completion):
        if self._completer.widget() is not self:
            return

        tc = self.textCursor()
        extra = len(completion) - len(self._completer.completionPrefix())
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.Left)
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfWord)

        if self.completion_prefix.lower() == completion[-extra:].lower():
            pass
            #print('You inserted the word after it was completed')
        else:
            tc.insertText(completion[-extra:])
            #print('The text being inserted',completion[-extra:])
            self.setTextCursor(tc)
            self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(self.all_autocomplete, self._completer))

    def textUnderCursor(self):
        tc = self.textCursor()
        tc.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)
        #print('Here is the selected text under the cursor' , tc.selectedText())
        return tc.selectedText()

    def focusInEvent(self, e):
        #Open the widget where you are at in the edit
        if self._completer is not None:
            self._completer.setWidget(self)
        super(TextEdit, self).focusInEvent(e)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):

        isShortcut = False

        if self._completer is not None and self._completer.popup().isVisible():
            #print('Popup is up')
            # The following keys are forwarded by the completer to the widget.
            if e.key() in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Escape, Qt.Key_Tab, Qt.Key_Backtab):
                e.ignore()
                #self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(self.all_autocomplete, self._completer))
                # Let the completer do default behavior.
                return

        if e.key() == Qt.Key_E and e.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
            #Control + E was pressed.
            words = self.all_autocomplete
            self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(words, self._completer))
            isShortcut = True

        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Period:
            #This is how I will do the lookup functionality. Show when period is his, open the list of options.
            self.textCursor().insertText('.')
            self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.PreviousWord)
            self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.PreviousWord, QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
            dict_key = self.textCursor().selectedText().upper()
            #print('Dict Key' , dict_key)
            self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextWord)
            self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextWord)

            #print(dict_key)
            words = self.auto_complete_dict[dict_key]
            self._completer.setModel(QStringListModel(words, self._completer))
            isShortcut = True

        if self._completer is None or not isShortcut:
            # Do not process the shortcut when we have a completer.
            super(TextEdit, self).keyPressEvent(e)

        ctrlOrShift = e.modifiers() & (Qt.ControlModifier | Qt.ShiftModifier)
        if self._completer is None or (ctrlOrShift and len(e.text()) == 0):
            return

        eow = "~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?,./;'[]\\-="
        hasModifier = (e.modifiers() != Qt.NoModifier) and not ctrlOrShift


        completionPrefix = self.textUnderCursor()
        self.completion_prefix = completionPrefix
        #print('CompletionPrefix :' , completionPrefix)

        if not isShortcut and (hasModifier or len(e.text()) == 0 or len(completionPrefix) < 2 or e.text()[-1] in eow):
            self._completer.popup().hide()
            return

        if completionPrefix != self._completer.completionPrefix():
            #Puts the Prefix of the word youre typing into the Prefix
            self._completer.setCompletionPrefix(completionPrefix)
            self._completer.popup().setCurrentIndex(
                    self._completer.completionModel().index(0, 0))

        cr = self.cursorRect()
        cr.setWidth(self._completer.popup().sizeHintForColumn(0) + self._completer.popup().verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width())
        self._completer.complete(cr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    '''These excepthook lines are to catch errors when using pyqt5'''
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook
    def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
        print(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.excepthook = exception_hook
    '''Error handling section to raise errors'''

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = sqlWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: So there was no other way to pass autocompleter to the initialized TextEdit class ? I want to do that while typing not only on init of the TextEdit class. That's not possible ? You couldn't just use

Comment: I could not find one when starting from the QDesigner UI file. I guess you could probably set a new QCompleter on the initialized TextEdit by emitting the signal from maybe a button click or whatever you need it to. Then reset it from there.